# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on custom class initialization

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have written the following class:

`.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class TDLPaneViewController;

@interface TDLSubViewController : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView* view;
@property (nonatomic, strong) TDLPaneViewController* paneViewController;

- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString*)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)viewWillDisppear:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)viewDidDisppear:(BOOL)animated;

@end
```

`.m`:

```
#import "TDLSubViewController.h"

@interface TDLSubViewController ()
{
     UIView *view;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* nibName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSBundle* nibBundle;

@end

@implementation TDLSubViewController

@synthesize paneViewController, view;
@synthesize nibName, nibBundle;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString*)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
          self.nibName = nibNameOrNil;
          self.nibBundle = nibBundleOrNil;
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     NSLog(@"viewWillAppear:%i", animated);
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     NSLog(@"viewDidAppear:%i", animated);
}
- (void)viewWillDisppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     NSLog(@"viewWillDisppear:%i", animated);
} 
- (void)viewDidDisppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     NSLog(@"viewDidDisppear:%i", animated);
}

@end
```

I get error when showing another view:
     - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
         [super viewDidAppear:animated];

```
     TDLTestSubViewController* subView = [[TDLTestSubViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TDLTestSubViewController" bundle:nil] ;

     [self pushSubViewController:nil animated:YES leftSide:YES];

}
```

TDLTestSubViewController is child class of TDLSubViewController.

If I use UIViewController instead of TDLTestSubViewController everything works fine and if I turn ARC off it's OK too. So I think the problem is in the TDLSubViewController class. Please, suggest what could be wrong?

Comment: why aren't you returning self from initWithNibName() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `initWithNibName:bundle:` method doesn't return `self` when it must.

Comment: Thus your problem isn't related to ARC or the fact you’re using Xcode4.6 or even iOS. It's a plain Objective-C problem.